# The best way to learn typing

Tags: keyboard, typing-speed

I want to learn fast typing. There are many online tools. I selected one and I am going through the lessons. I have couple concerns and I am not sure they are valid:

1. The tool shows the image of keyboard and highlights the position of the next letter. I noticed I look on image, not on text, and it helps me to type faster. It is hard to switch to text because image is very helpful and it is close to the text, so I see it anyway. Is it good or bad?
2. When I do typo, the tool shows a red signal and expects me to press right key. However, in real life, I need to press 'Backspace' if I do typo. Is it good or bad?

Are there studies that prove that image help to learn and that it is ok to learn without 'Backspace'?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is primarily opinion-based. Whether these conventions are good or bad depends on a lot of factors, including your learning style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is that you find yourself some online type-speed and type-training tools, just by doing a quick google search, and then just try to use the 10 finger system in your everyday life. It's ok to look where you're fingers are at the start cause your body needs to learn where the keys are, but over time you shall get more and more used to looking at the screen instead of the keyboard.

When you learned the basics the best tactic is to train, train in you're everyday life, and train on type-speed testers.

I myself is new to the 10 finger system and is trying to type this without looking at the keyboard